# How to set ollama temperature from command line

Tags: llm

I can run prompts from the command line like so:

```
ollama run mixtral:latest 'Why is the sky blue?'
```

But how do I change the temperature?

I know that in the interactive mode (the REPL), I can run `/set parameter temperature 0.0` to change the temperature. But how do I do this when I pass the prompt in the command line? Is there an option I can pass?

Comment: You can't set it directly, you need to create a custom model first. The temperature is part of the custom model, see [this thread](https://github.com/ollama/ollama/issues/2505).